# Axios POST request returned Undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, post, axios, undefined

I'm trying to build react-native fuction to make POST request to an API using Axios. The function seems to work but i keep getting the response as undefined. I've tested POST request with Postman, it works normally.

```
{
    "CaThuHoiList": [
        {
            "NGAY": "20-01-2020",
            "TH_ID": 33,
            "CA": 1,
            "CT_DONVI_ID": 78,
            "CREATE_BY": 4797,
            "TRANG_THAI": "HT",
            "CREATE_DATE": "20-01-2020 00:00",
            "KHO_ID": null,
            "LOAI": "TT"
        },
        {
            "NGAY": "20-01-2020",
            "TH_ID": 34,
            "CA": 1,
            "CT_DONVI_ID": 78,
            "CREATE_BY": 4797,
            "TRANG_THAI": "BD",
            "CREATE_DATE": "20-01-2020 00:00",
            "KHO_ID": null,
            "LOAI": "TL"
        }
    ],
    "Status": 1,
    "Message": ""
}
```

However i couldn't get the same response (undefined) while running my function:

```
onPostJson = () => {
  axios.post('https://10.1.127.17:11111/vpdu/get-ca-thu-hoi', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          FromDate: "01-Jan-2020",
          ToDate: "01-Feb-2020",
          Ca: 1
        })
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      data = response;
      console.log(data); \\Storing response in data still getting undefined
      return response;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have data pulled out. I have done the changes. You may check out.

```
     onPostJson = () => {
         let configObject = {
        "url": "https://10.1.127.17:11111/vpdu/get-ca-thu-hoi",
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
"data":{
                  "FromDate": "01-Jan-2020",
                  "ToDate": "01-Feb-2020",
                  "Ca": 1
                }
        
    }}
axios.request(configObject ).then((res) => {
          console.log("react1: ", res);
          console.log("react2: ", res.data);
          
      })
}
```

Comment: Can you just `console.log(res)` and show me what you are getting

Comment: try this way to do POST request and see the results. I have updated answer

Comment: Than I believe their is definitely some issue with your POST request, you may first try it on Postman and see if its working

Comment: Great to hear that. You may upvote the answer as well as a gift. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const inserrequest=async () => {
    let addreq = await axios.post('http://xxxxxx..//Employee/PostInsertrequest',
         {
             ReqEmpCode: 'xxxxxx', 
         });
    console.warn(JSON.stringify(addreq.data));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).